# App to execute another app

Tags: android

I want an App to execute another app

When in device booting I set the intent filter.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

because of this, the Main app start. In the Main App, I only want to execute another app once

I try this.

**Main**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreference wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("another app package name");
        startActivity(intent);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN, false);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

but this code is not working. perhaps anybody knows another way to do it?

Thanks

add

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
    if (isFirstRun) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AutoUpdate.class));
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
        editor.apply();
        finish();
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer to action ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED you need to implement Broadcast receiver registered in manifest. Your application must also use permission RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.

Please refer here for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED

Please note, an application must run ui elements at least once for the receiver to be able to register for this action.

Then override the onReceive method of your receiver to start your application. Also note, you must add NEW_TASK flag when starting activity from receiver context.

Comment: thanks , but your answer seem to not correct .  I want when I start Main App,     app update inspection app start only once execute.   so I try `startActivity`

Comment: I must   when device booting, Main app start     so I add boot completed action.

Comment: Then you need broadcast receiver. Your activity can only be started on boot with broadcast receiver

Comment: so, once execute in  boot completed action ?

Comment: Yes. You can save in preferences that first launch was done by using boolean. And check for that boolean when you implement onReceive method of receiver.

Comment: thanks.  please check add my comment.  I try this sharedPreference. but is not use

Comment: You're doing it from the activity. Activity cannot receive boot completed action. Implement receiver if you need it to run on boot.

Comment: this class is boot completed action class.

Comment: Yes but it's not broadcast receiver. It's an activity.

Comment: my code   first extends BroadcastReceiver  `if (action.equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")){ startActivity(my this class);`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I do it like this. I don't use the `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

Here is my code:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreference wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
        if (isFirstRun) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class));
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

            editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
            editor.apply();
            finish();
        } 
    }     
}
```

and in the **AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: thanks, but I have a question.  my Main app first SplashActivity.class start.     showing 5 second. and finish 5 second showing main.class

Comment: so I think my main.class manifest not add intent-filter   `android.intent.action.MAIN` ,  `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`.

Comment: and I want another app `startActivity`

Comment: you can do the same in your SlashActivity but make youre splash activity to have the intent filter of  `android.intent.action.MAIN`

Comment: @조현욱 did it works? sorry, i cant understand you're english correctly

Comment: I try add my comment code.   but it is not work.  not go startActivity(AutoUpdate.class)

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AutoUpdate.class));`    this part . not going AutoUpdate.class

Comment: not error logcat.  it is normal work . but only not going AutoUpdate.class

Comment: I think   when `boolean isFirstRun = true;  startActivity(AutoUpdate.class),  and autoupdate finish, isFirstRun =false`    do you know this way?

Comment: sorry but I barely cant understand youre question

Comment: sorry, I 'm english not well.    I want when `boolean FR = true  -> AutoUpdate work.  and boolean FR = false not work.`  so I think SharedPreference. I don't know how to use sharedPreference

Comment: try to put a `Toast` in you're if else or use breakpoint to see the value of you're `SharedPreference`